# Enable Apple Music on iTunes

Tags: itunes, apple-music

I'm unable to activate Apple Music on iTunes 12.7

When I go to Preferences -> General There is no Show Apple Music option.
Apple music works fine on my iPhone.

How do I enable Apple Music on iTunes?

[image]

Comment: Did you look under "iTunes > Preferences > Restrictions", if "Apple Music" has been disabled?

Comment: I just checked and its not disabled. @Redarm

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to go to Account on the top bar and then click Authorisations-> De-Authorise This Computer and Authorise again.
After this the Apple music will be shown in iTunes Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

First be sure you are logged in with the same Apple ID on both devices.  Then go to iTunes > Music, and click on "For You"  You can then either choose "Try it now" (if you do not have a subscription) or "Connect"